# Prevent [Game player Id ]from keeping increasing in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I tried to make my own `Tic Tac Toe game`, so I created two activities (`MainActivity, GameActivity`), the second activity contains a `Fragment` which displays `gridView`.for storing score and playes'name i created a `Player` class,every player has a uniq `ID` which generated when player object get constructed.

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    Button start;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start);

        start.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

**GameActivity**

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity 
{


Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        getActionBar().hide();      
        loadFragment(fragment,savedInstanceState);


    }

    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment,Bundle bundle){

        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction(); 

         fragment=new gameFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.grid_container,fragment,"this");
transaction.commit();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onDestroy();

    }


}
```

**GameFragment**

```
public class gameFragment extends Fragment
{
    GameGridAdapter adapter;
    GridView gv;
     boolean isGameOver=false;
    Player playerOne,playerTwo,currentPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method

        init();
        super.onAttach(context);

    }   

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_grid,container,false);  

        gv=(GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid);

        adapter=new GameGridAdapter(getActivity());

        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"player id "+ playerOne.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterViewAnimator.OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View view, int pos, long viewId)
                {
                // TODO: Implement this method

        return view;

        }

        public void init(){     

                playerOne=new Player();

            playerTwo=new Player();


        }
}
```

My problem is whenever i press return button in gameFragment and return to it second time  the id in Player object increases its like i created a new object.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is - you are creating a new object every time. There are a few approaches on how to make your objects more/less persistent: from easier to more complex.

For your particular case - I'd recommend creating and storing your players in the `Application` class. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.

You will have to create your implementation of the android.app.Application

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

    public Player player1;
    public Player player2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        player1 = new Player();
        player2 = new Player();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to mention it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">
</application>
```

And then access your player objects by getting the application context:

```
Player player1 = ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).player1;
Player player2 = ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).player2;
```

I have to warn you that this approach is rarely recommended, and would like to point you to some Dependency Injection frameworks, like `Dagger` or `Koin (for Kotlin)`.

Also, note that the objects will wanish if your application is destroyed by the user or the system.

Comment: Thank you for your help.i wonder why new objects is being created? isn't leaving fragment  makes any object in it null?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "leaving fragment", but the `onAttach()` will be called every time you open the fragment from your `GameActivity`.

Comment: Also, the objects inside the Fragment will remain what they are, but they will be gone from the system sooner or later. English is not my main language, so it's pretty hard to describe in a comment, but some discovering about Garbage Collection will help you to gain some deeper understanding.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview

Comment: i realised that when i return to MainActivity the static variable "playerCounter" holds it value and when i return to gameActivity  its create new objects which use the static variable for initialising player id